# Parsing iCal/vCal/Google calendar files in C++

Tags: c++, mfc, icalendar, google-calendar-api, vcalendar

Can anyone recommend a ready-to-use class/library compatible with C/C++/MFC/ATL that would parse iCal/vCal/Google calendar files (with recurrences)? It can be free or commercial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is a [parser in PHP for iCal](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/3278.html), you can downloaded and check the code to suit your language.

for vCal/vCard parsing [there's a C Library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ccard).

for Google Calendar I couldn't find any exact answer, so, try to Google it.

Comment: Thank you. The Google calendar should be just an iCal, which is basically a vCal in the end :) I'll take a look at that C library you posted a link to and see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

For vCal you can try the [CCard](http://ccard.sourceforge.net/) project on SourceForge:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/ccard

It's a C library but it states Windows as a supported platform.

*Edit: balexandre already linked to it :)

Comment: Thank you - I'll try it later tonight/tomorrow and see if it works. I only need vCal, I just hope the name "CCard" doesn't assume only vCard processing :)

Answer (score 1):

The only problem with the CCard project is that it's a generic parser (similar to what I already have implemented myself) - what would be really valuable to me is something that "understands" all varieties of recurrences and such. Those differ between vCal and iCal as well, adding to the complexity.